# Show form fields only if the value of another field is X

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to show form fields only if the user inputs a specific value in a different field. Specifically, I am asking users to input the number of children they have. If the user inputs 1, then a set of fields will appear for the user to add additional information on their child. If the user inputs 2, then 2 sets of fields will appear, one per child. From a JS perspective, I am looking to hide the field sets based on the response.

This is my HTML:
Form field based on which the JS should be based on:

```
 <html>
<div class="_form_element _field10 _full_width ">
          <label for="field[10]" class="_form-label">
            How many children do you have? <span style="color: #eb636d;">*</span>
          </label>
          <div class="_field-wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="field[10]" name="field[10]" value="" placeholder="" required />
          </div>
        </div>
</html>
```

Field set to appear based on value entered in the field above:

```
<html>
<div id=1 class="child_1">
        <div class="_form_element _field51 _full_width " >
          <label for="field[51]" class="_form-label">
            First child's name
          </label>
          <div class="_field-wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="field[51]" name="field[51]" value="" placeholder="" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_form_element _field55 _full_width " >
          <label for="field[55]" class="_form-label">
            First child's birthdate
          </label>
          <div class="_field-wrapper">
            <input type="date" class="date_field" id="field[55]" name="field[55]" value="" placeholder=""  />
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</html>
```

Thanks